# Вычисление максимального значения контейнера

Tags: qt, qt5

Как можно, максимально быстро вычислить элемент, который имеет самое большое значение, в контейнере QVector?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [std::max_element](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). Естественно, если элементы вектора не численные, придется определять свой оператор сравнения. Для получения индекса найденного элемента нужно использовать [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Comment: Про него читал, а стандартных методов у QT нету выходит? Просто искал стандартные и не нашел.

Comment: Стандартная библиотека С++ все равно подключается. А данные шаблонные функции с Qt-контейнерами работают. То, что разработчики решили не дублировать функционал - просто прекрасно.

Comment: А как ее использоваться с данными типа double, у меня в контейнере x1 переменные с запятой. Преобразовывать их в int? `double result  = std::max_element(x1.begin(), x1.end());` такой код выдает ошибку.

Comment: Нужен пример кода, название компилятора и текст ошибки.И да ... `std::max_element` возвращает итератор - это надо учитывать, чтобы не ловить ошибки)

Comment: А у вас сайт сломался (который majestio.info)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin , увы - просто нет времени восстановить, новый проект просто пока не оставляет время. Но я постараюсь.